# get position of each item clicked in Listview after GridView

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I devised intents between GridView and List view. When I click the item of the gridview , next intent related with listview is opened. Then, When I click the item of list view, the new intent is opened to show a text related with each item of listview.

There is an object with arraylist and the object is also in the arraylist.
Gridview is shown to list each object of arraylist.
Listview is shown to list each item of arraylist in the object.

I got the item first girdview and first listview.

I have an issue how to get the each positon of gridview and list view.

Here is the code which is in the last intent below.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"London",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AttactivePlacesActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position_griditem_one",position);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Paris",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AttactivePlacesActivity.class)
                            .putExtra("position_griditem_two",position));
                    break;

        }
    });
```

AttactivePlacesActivity

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                switch(position){

                    case 0:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"London Object",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(AttactivePlacesActivity.this,AttactivePlaceObject.class);
                        intent.putExtra("position_listitem_one",position);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    case 1: 
                        startActivity(new Intent(AttactivePlacesActivity.this,AttactivePlaceObject.class)
                                .putExtra("position_listitem_two",position));
                        break;


                }


            }
        });
```

AttactivePlaceObject

```
// get from a previous gridview to get each item of gridview
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridlist);

        // get from a previous listview to get each item of listview
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewAttactivePlaces);


        //gridView.getItemIdAtPosition();

        //listView.getItemIdAtPosition();


        ImageView attractivePlaceImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.attractive_place_image);

        TextView attractivePlaceInformation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attractive_place_detailed_information);


        ImageView location = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.location_icon);


        attractivePlaceImage.setImageResource(
                cityAttactivePlaces.get(0).getAttactivePlaces().get(0).getmAttaticePlaceImageResourceId());


        attractivePlaceInformation.setText(cityAttactivePlaces.get(0).getAttactivePlaces().get(0).getPlaceDetailInformation());
```

My aim
When I click London , Attractive places of London is listed. When I click Paris, Attractive places of Paris is listed. any attractive places of any city is clicked , detailed information is shown as Last intent.

How do I get gridview and listviews' position to show last intent.

Answer (score 1):

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),position+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Intent intent = new Intent(AttactivePlacesActivity.this,AttactivePlaceObject.class);
                        intent.putExtra("position",position);
                        startActivity(intent);

                 }
            });
```

Note-- The intent should be sent by an activity and must be recieved by an activity.

Comment: listivew and gridview setonItemClickListener in previous intents. I already defined them. How do I reach gridview item(position 2) and listview (position 1)  ->  like this information.setText(c.get(2).getText().get(1).getInformation()); . The problem is there without using numbers.

Comment: you mean to say if you click position one on the list you want that position number in the next activity. isnt it?

Comment: Correct. But I don'T know setonItemClickListener is defined or not in the class because of defining previous intents. How can I want to accces it.

Comment: you can do this like when you are using your intent to change the activity then by using "intentInstance.putExtra("key", "value");" this function you can send much of the data to another activity and you can recieve this data in the another activity as "Intent intent= getIntent(); dataType variable= intent.getStringExtra("same key");"

Comment: there is lot of overloads available for this. you can give this a try

Comment: Can you write the code intentInstance.putExtra in my code to show how to define gridview position and listview position if it is possible.

Comment: I have edited my piece of code. try to implement this in your code. If not working post a slight more data from you code.

Comment: I wrote what you wrote. So, How can I access each position of gridview and listview in my code.

Comment: Add toast to you code and check if the value is coming as you wanted or not

Comment: I got the positions of each item of gridview and listview. After that, How should I do to show information and image according to them.